# How do I convert multi-index columns to singular by picking different levels for each column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, multi-index

I have a data from emenated from .Xlsx file that has merged cells of headears on top. consequently the header that I used for reading the file is the first 4 rows, and that causes me having unwanted column names as multi index.
I tried many things to be able to `reorder_levels()` column by column until I have all the indexes I desire on the first level, so then simply use `drop_level()` to drop last 3 levels and end up with singular column names for each, but apperantly there is no way to do so column by column and these functions only operate on the entire Dataframe columns.

```
Here is an exmple of what I have.

| Unnamed: 0_level_1  || Unnamed: 1_level_0  | 50Percentile        |
| Location Description|| Unnamed: 1_level_1  | Unnamed: 2_level_1  |
| Unnamed: 0_level_2  || Bulletin 17C        | Unnamed: 2_level_2  |
| Unnamed: 0_level_3  || Unnamed: 1_level_3  | Unnamed: 2_level_3  |
| ------------------- || ------------------- | ------------------- |
|        Cell 1       ||        Cell 1       |        Cell 1       |
|        Cell 2       ||        Cell 2       |        Cell 2       |

And here is what I expect to get.

| Location Description|| Bulletin 17C        | 50Percentile        |
| ------------------- || ------------------- | ------------------- |
|        Cell 1       ||        Cell 1       |        Cell 1       |
|        Cell 2       ||        Cell 2       |        Cell 2       |
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide the constructor of your DataFrame, it's annoying to generate MultiIndexed DataFrames from text. You can provide a dictionary using `df.to_dict('tight')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to get the first non-Unnamed level for each column (or `None` if all levels are Unnamed):

```
df.columns = [next((x for x in level if not x.startswith('Unnamed')), None)
              for level in df.columns]
```

Output:

```
  Location Description Bulletin 17C 50Percentile
0               Cell 1       Cell 1       Cell 1
1               Cell 2       Cell 2       Cell 2
```